# How to identify the position of the first occurring local minimum in a vector?

Tags: r

Say I have the following vector:

```
     y
 [1] 10
 [2] 9
 [3] 8
 [4] 6
 [5] 7
 [6] -3
 [7] -1
```

Though the position of the minimum can be get using `which(y==min(y)` as 6. But I want to know how to get the first minimum which is `6` and the position is `4`. After 6 the value increased to 7.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is 6 the minimum?

Comment: value 6 is the first lowest value as after that it increases to 7 then decreases to -3. Sorry for my language and ambiguity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
first.min <- function(y) {
  d <- which(diff(y) > 0)
  if (length(d) > 0) d[1] else length(y)
}
first.min(y)
##[1] 4
```

This gives you the position. To get the minimum value:

```
y[first.min(y)]
##[1] 6
```

---

#### Update version that accounts for first minimum over multiple elements

Suppose you have the case:

```
y <- c(10,9,6,6,7,-3,-1)
```

and you want to find the position of the first `6` as the position of the first minimum. Then, the above function needs to be modified to:

```
first.min <- function(y) {
  d <- diff(y)
  p <- which(d > 0)
  if (length(p) > 0) p <- p[1] else p <- length(y)
  n <- which(d[1:p[1]] < 0)
  if (length(n) > 0) n[length(n)]+1 else 1
}
```

Here, we detect the first position of the positive difference as before, but we backtrack to check the position of the last negative difference and return that position plus one. Of course, in this case if we still do want the position of the second `6`, then we still need the previous version.

To check:

```
## As before
y <- c(10,9,8,6,7,-3,-1)
first.min(y)
##[1] 4
y[first.min(y)]
##[1] 6

## New case
y <- c(10,9,6,6,7,-3,-1)
first.min(y)
##[1] 3
y[first.min(y)]
##[1] 6

## 6 is not a minimum, but -3 is
y <- c(10,9,8,6,6,-3,-1)
first.min(y)
##[1] 6
y[first.min(y)]
##[1] -3

## Edge case where minimum is at end
y <- c(10,9,8,6,5)
first.min(y)
##[1] 5
y[first.min(y)]
##[1] 5

## Edge case where minimum is at last 2 elements, but we want
## the first of these
y <- c(10,9,8,6,6)
first.min(y)
##[1] 4
y[first.min(y)]
##[1] 6
```

Answer (score 3):

This might work also:

```
y <- c(10,9,8,6,7,-3,-1)
which(diff(y) > 0)
# [1] 4 6
y[ head(which(diff(y) > 0L), n = 1) ]
# [1] 6
```

Depending on your required output, you can choose between your indexing. When there is a local peak to find, both of these methods are fine:

```
y[ which(diff(y) > 0)[1] ]
# [1] 6
y[ head(which(diff(y) > 0), n = 1) ]
# [1] 6
```

However, when there is no peak to find, they act differently:

```
y2 <- c(10,9,8,6,5,5,-1,-3)
y2[ which(diff(y2) > 0)[1] ]
# [1] NA
y2[ head(which(diff(y2) > 0), n = 1) ]
# numeric(0)
```

Which one you choose depends on how you handle "failure". (It's often a matter of style/preference, though some may argue that though `NA` may be legitimate in some circumstances.)

Comment: it gives *both* the value *and* the index, over to you to use the correct one (I thought it was clear with the code)

Answer (score 1):

Adding an edge case to @r2evans solution

```
get.first.min.pos <- function(y) ifelse(sum(diff(y) > 0) > 0, 
                                        which(diff(y) > 0)[1], length(y)) 
y <- c(10,9,8,6,7,-3,-1)
get.first.min.pos(y)
[1] 4

y <- c(10,9,8,6)
get.first.min.pos(y)
[1] 4
```

Comment: good thought; though I hadn't assumed it would be necessary, it's good to give the OP the option, thanks for the suggestion